On the absolute continuity of a particular functions.
We consider $f\in L^1[a,b]$, where $F$ is a finite interval of $\mathbb{R}$. The function $F\colon [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as $$F(x):=\int_{[a,x]}f\;d\lambda\quad(x\in [a,b])$$
it is called integral function with respect to the function $f$. It is easily shown that $F$ is absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$.
Now, we extend the definition of $F$ as follows:
$$F(x):=F(b)\quad\text{for}\quad x>b$$
Now,  for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we consider the function $$G_n(x):=\frac{F\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)-F(x)}{\frac{1}{n}}\quad x\in [a,b]$$
It seems completely obvious to me that $G_n$ is also absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, but I can't show it.
My attempt
To show that $F_n(x)$ is absolutely continuous in $[a,b]$  it is enough to prove that the function $$x\mapsto F\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ is absolutely continuous in $[a,b]$. We know that the extended $F$ function is absolutely continuous in $[a,\infty)$, and then for $\varepsilon > 0$ fixed exists $\delta >0$ such that if $\{[a_k, b_k]\; |\; k=1,\dots N\}$ is a finite collection of non-overlapping closed intervals contained in $[a,\infty)$ with $\sum(b_k-a_k)<\delta$ we have that $$\sum_{k=1}^N\lvert F(b_k)-F(a_k)\rvert<\varepsilon.$$ We observe that $\{[a_k+\frac{1}{n},b_k+\frac{1}{n}]\;|\: k=1\dots, N\}$ is a finite collection of non-overlapping intervals contained in $[a,\infty)$ such that $$\sum_{k=1}^N\left[\left(b_k+\frac{1}{n}\right)-\left(a_k+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right]=\sum_{k=1}^N(b_k-a_k)<\delta,$$ and so, since $F$ is absolutely continuous in $[a,\infty)$ we have that $$\sum_{k=1}^N \left\lvert F\left(b_k+\frac{1}{n}\right)-F\left(a_k+\frac{1}{n}\right) \right\rvert<\varepsilon,$$ then the function $$x\mapsto F\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ is absolutely continuous in $[a,\infty)$ and in particular is absolutely continous in $[a,b]$.

Could you please tell me if what I have done is formally correct? Thanks!


Extended $F$ is also absolutelly continuous, right? Then, note that $\sum_{k=1}^n (b_k - a_k) = \sum_{k=1}^n ( b_k + \frac{1}{n}   - (a_k + \frac{1}{n}))$.

Sums and scalar multiples of AC functions are AC, so it suffices to show that $x \mapsto F(x+1/n)$ is AC. Can you relate the values of $F(x+1/n)$ on the endpoints of nonoverlapping intervals to the values of $F(x)$?

@WhileIAmI edited the post under your hint, I hope it is correct now.
